# Find a counterexample of: If $1_{A}+1_{B}$ is a random variable then $A$ and $B$ are measurable

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

I was trying to prove the following proposition, if  $1_{A}+1_{B}$ is a random variable then $A$ and $B$ are measurable.

Where $1_{A}$ is the indicator, function given by

\begin{equation}
1_{A}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \ \   x \in A \\
0, \ \   x \notin A
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I proved that the converse is true. Here's the proof:

Let $A$ and $B$ be measurable sets, i.e, $A$, $B \in \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

If $x<0$ then $(1_{A}+1_{B}\leq x ) =  \emptyset \in  \mathbb{F} $

if $x \in [0,1)$ then $(1_{A}+1_{B}\leq x ) = (A \cup B)^{\complement} \in \mathbb{F} $

if $x \in [1,2) $ then $ (1_{A}+1_{B} \leq x ) = (A \cap B )^{ \complement } \in \mathbb{F} $

if $x \geq 2  $ then $ (1_{A}+1_{B} \leq x ) = \Omega \in \mathbb{F} $

This implies that $1_{A}+1_{B}$ is random variable.

But not able to prove that if  $1_{A}+1_{B}$ is a random variable then $A$ and $B$ are measurable. I don't know where to start.

**I have the following Questions:**

1. Do you know a counterexample to this proposition?
2. Do you have an idea that could help me to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there's the obvious counterexample : $1_A + 1_{A^C} = 1$ for any $A$, so take a non-measurable $A$ and you are done, since $1$ is measurable but $A,A^c$ aren't. Regarding your proof, you will need some corrections : note that $\{1_A + 1_B \leq 2\} = \Omega$, so you'll have to make some corrections to the numbers and sets , but of course your intentions and the use of the definition are appropriate. +1 to your question, the basic principle I used for the counterexample is that even if functions are non-measurable, by patching them their sum can easily be measurable.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon You're brilliant! Thank you so much. Now I understand it.

Comment: Oh , that's good to know @tnt235711! (131719?) Good luck for the future, and if you manage to modify your attempt so that it's correct and want feedback, let me know. I hope you are doing a course on measure theory, it's utterly utterly rewarding to go through MSE's question bank (use the search box or Google) for measure theory. You'll get so many questions that have already been answered, and you'll do very well.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes! 131719, Thank you, I modified the proof given above.

Comment: You'll need to cover all $x \in \mathbb R$. Right now, for example, you are missing the cases $x=0.5$ and so on : but it's easy to modify the proof @tnt235711 to cover these cases : for example, for all $0\leq x<1$ we have $\{1_A + 1_B \leq x \}= A^C \cup B^C$ and so on for the missing parts. Once you see this, you will have covered all $x \in \mathbb R$ and will be done!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I think that in the case where  $x \in [0,1)$  then $\{ 1_{A}+1_{B} \leq x \} = A^{C} \cap B^{C} $.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I meant $A^C \cap B^C$, but you get the idea. Now something similar for $x \in [1,2)$ and you are done.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You are welcome!